# Setting Request header: Connection

Tags: http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

By default `Connection` Header is set to `Keep-Alive` in browers, to make it possible to keep connection open for further requests from browser.

When I make `Connection` header to `close`, what may be the difference ?
Will that affect any performance issue ?

(one addition: I am setting header from xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Why would you want to tamper with something like that?

Comment: i am getting Empty response from server for the request. i am taking this into  consideration then

Comment: Maybe the `statusCode: 204 no content` was being set? This can interfere.

Answer (score 20):

When you make requests with "**Connection: keep-alive**" the subsequent request to the server will use the same TCP connection. This is called HTTP persistent connection. This helps in reducing CPU load on the server side and improves latency/response time.

If a request is made with "**Connection: close**" this indicates that once the request has been made the server needs to close the connection. And so for each request a new TCP connection will be established.

By default HTTP 1.1 client/server uses keep-alive whereas HTTP 1.0 client/server doesn't support keep-alive by default.

Comment: I think your answer about `Connection: close` in the request is wrong. According to [HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), `Connection: close` in either the request or the response header fields indicates that the connection SHOULD NOT be considered `persistent' after the current request/response is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It affects performance, because most expensive resources create a socket between two machines. So the client needs to establish a new connection in every request.

Comment: That's assuming it's possible to change it from within an xmlhttprequest.

Comment: I need to along with this is that, is this create a request/response stream to server and keep this stream open forever for further communication with server or something else

Comment: @bzlm yes i am changing it from xmlhttprequest

Comment: @neworld so when one should set Connection to close ? can you give me some example .

Comment: @this-abhi: I think, you dont need close connection self. It's unnecessary. But I you totaly know you generate last request, you can close.

Comment: @this-abhi, I don't think you're going to have much luck with this. You're supposed to let the browser and server negotiate the communication amongst themselves. Fiddling with the `Connection` header isn't probably even going to work.

Comment: @bzlm , neoworld okay , then i will be better off the hook of this

Answer (score 0):

this article has graphically demonstrated what would happen in such a when the connection header is set to closed and also keep-alive.
It helped me understand it and I hope it helps you too.
[The Benefits of Connection Keep Alive](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/http-keep-alive/)